# Find equation of tangent

Tags: calculus

We have to find the equations of the tangents drawn to the curve $y^2 – 2x^3– 4y + 8 = 0$ from the point $(1, 2)$.

I tried differentiating the equation to find the slope.

$$2yy'-6x^2 - 4y'=0$$

but $(1,2)$ does not satisfy the curve. Then how can we solve it.

Comment: Remember that $y$ is a function of $x$. So, differentiating $4y$ yields $4y'$ not $4$, as shown in your solution.

Answer (score 4):

$$2x^3=y^2-4y+8$$

If $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the curve $$2x_1^3=y_1^2-4y_1+8\ \ \ \ (1)$$

The equation of the tangent at $(x_1,y_1)$
$$\dfrac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\dfrac{6x_1^2}{2y_1-4}$$

Now as it has to pass through $(1,2)$

$$\dfrac{2-y_1}{1-x_1}=\dfrac{6x_1^2+4}{2y_1}\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Solve $(1),(2)$ for $x_1,y_1$

Comment: OP got wrong y' I suppose

Comment: @Ramanujan, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$2yy'-6x^2 -4y'=0$

$y'=\frac{6x^2}{2y-4}$

Now put x=1,y=2

Comment: (1,2) does not lie on the curve